# jQuery tablesorter doesnt work for me

Tags: jquery, html, tablesorter

I'm trying to learn jQuery and tablesorter (http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) caught my eye. I wanted to see if I can use this. I am having problems just having it sort in the first place.

this is my HTML code, and it just doesn't sort for me. Help a beginner out?

```js
 $(function() {
   $("#myTable").tablesorter({
     sortList: [
       [0, 0],
       [1, 0]
     ]
   });
 });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.22.1/css/theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.22.1/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.22.1/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Due</th>
      <th>Web Site</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>jsmith@gmail.com</td>
      <td>$50.00</td>
      <td>http://www.jsmith.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bach</td>
      <td>Frank</td>
      <td>fbach@yahoo.com</td>
      <td>$50.00</td>
      <td>http://www.frank.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>Jason</td>
      <td>jdoe@hotmail.com</td>
      <td>$100.00</td>
      <td>http://www.jdoe.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Conway</td>
      <td>Tim</td>
      <td>tconway@earthlink.net</td>
      <td>$50.00</td>
      <td>http://www.timconway.com</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you post the expected results to make this question a bit clearer?

Comment: @JNYRanger sorry about that, the headers arent clickable. Should be able to click on the contents of the TH tag and sort the values

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console when you put your browser in dev mode?  (Usually F12)

Comment: Make sure to load jQuery *first*

Answer (score 2):

I copied your code into a test ([Here](http://jsfiddle.net/gws000/454fc601/13)) and it seems to behave normally.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tablesorter/js/jQuery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"></script>
```

Have you verified the paths of all the referenced libraries you are using?  If you are an absolute beginner with tablesorter, the examples in the master library might be handy ([Here](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter)).

Comment: This works because jQuery is loaded before the tablesorter plugin